# How to escape a ":" in a bibliographic reference with pandoc?

Tags: haskell, markdown, pandoc, bibtex, bibliography

Basically, a have a bibtex file that gets automatically generated by Zotero 4.0.17 and I am using it to generate the bibliography in a markdown file. The tools used are pandoc-1.12.1 and pandoc-citeproc-0.2 .

This is the markdown file named `notes.md`

```
# State of the art

 - Wikipathways [@pico_wikipathways\:_2008]

# Bibliography

<!-- TODO is this usefull?
bibliography::research.bib -->
<!-- \bibliography{research} So that RefTeX knows about the bibliography -->
```

This is the bibtex file named `research.bib`

```
@ARTICLE{pico_wikipathways:_2008,
 author = {Pico, Alexander R and Kelder, Thomas and van Iersel, Martijn P and Hanspers, Kristina and Conklin, Bruce R and Evelo, Chris},
 title = {{WikiPathways:} Pathway Editing for the People},
 journal = {{PLoS} Biol},
 year = {2008},
 volume = {6},
 pages = {e184},
 number = {7},
 month = jul,
 abstract = {{WikiPathways} provides a collaborative platform for creating, updating, and sharing pathway diagrams and serves as an example of content  curation by the biology community.},
 doi = {10.1371/journal.pbio.0060184},
 keywords = {\_tablet},
 shorttitle = {{WikiPathways}},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.0060184},
 urldate = {2013-11-20}
}
```

And this is the command I run

```
pandoc --bibliography=research.bib notes.md -o notes.md.pdf
```

I was expecting everything to go fine but the presence of a `:` character makes the generation of a PDF succeed with the following error

```
pandoc-citeproc: reference pico_wikipathways not found
```

The PDF will have an incorrect bibliography.

Any idea how to escape the `:` in `notes.md` so that the bibliographic reference gets recognized?

Comment: FYI. I got some interesting suggestion for workarounds at https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/34228/how-do-i-stop-zotero-export-to-bibtex-from-using-problematic-nonalphanumeric-characters-in-keys/

Comment: FYI2. This problem is fixed in pandoc's master branch now. Check https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/b9b1546ed238ca8fd4d65a6e02fa7ecbf9a4be65 for details.

Comment: FYI3. This problem was permanently fixed in [pandoc 1.12.3.1](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/releases.html#pandoc-1.12.3-10-jan-2014).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to change your key.  Pandoc's citation key parser doesn't currently allow more than one non-alphanumeric symbol in a row, so the key with `:_` fails.  Also, don't use a backslash before the `:` in a citation key.

Comment: As I said, the keys get generated automatically from Zotero. Which means it is not easy for me to do what you suggest. I will try to see if there is a way to change the rules for generation of keys but I am not exactly sure how.

Comment: Probably easier to change pandoc to allow these keys.  Submit an issue if you like at http://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues.

Comment: I just noticed your name. Thank you for Pandoc as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue has been fixed as of version 1.12.3.  Uninstall your current version using

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/pandoc /usr/local/doc/pandoc-1.9.4.2 /usr/local/share/man/man1/pandoc.1.gz /usr/local/share/man/man5/pandoc_markdown.5.gz /usr/local/share/pandoc-1.9.4.2
```

then reinstall pandoc and you should be good to go.

Comment: Please notice my comments in the question itself.